# Unable to use CURL within GROOVY script for a REST PUT call

Tags: rest, curl, groovy, get, put

I am trying to do a simple PUT request using CURL. Simple it is on a terminal but not able to get it working within my Groovy script.

Here is a snippet of it :-

```
class Test {
  //Throws 415 Cannot Consume Content Type    
  void testPUT () {
  println "curl -i -X PUT -H \"Content-Type: application/json\" -d '{\"Key1\":1, \"Key2\":\"Value2\"}' http://<hostname>/foo/".execute().text
 }

  // Works Perfectly Fine
  void testGET () {
  println "curl -i -X GET -H \"Content-Type: application/json\" http://<hostname>/foo".execute().text
 }
}
```

I also tried to enclose the command using triple quotes like:-

```
 """curl -i -X PUT -H "Content-Type:application/json" -d '{"Key1":1,"Key2":"Value2"}' http://<hostname>/foo""".execute().text
```

All my attempts just gives **415 Content Type Cannot be Consumed**

**When I simply use the curl command on a terminal window, both PUT and GET methods work fine.**

Am I missing something? Any help would be appreciated!

Thank You!

Comment: So, you're saying that the curl command your test script is outputting doesn't work, but you typing _the exact same thing_ into a terminal does?

Comment: yes that is whats happening :(

Comment: Try running it through a logging proxy to see what's on the wire.

Comment: @ Dave Newton:- Could you please give more details on what to look for

Answer (score 10):

Try using the list variation of the string and see if that works:

```
println ["curl", "-i", "-X PUT", "-H 'Content-Type:application/json'", "-d '{\"Key1\":1, \"Key2\":\"Value2\"}'", "http://<hostname>/foo/"].execute().text
```

I was having a similar problem and this was the only way I could find to solve it. Groovy will split the string into arguments at each space and I suspect this was tripping up Curl and the -H argument pair. By putting the string into the list variant, it keeps each item together as an argument.

Comment: Yes indeed, I had a space in between `Content-Type` and `application/json`, removing just that made everything to work again and the correct `Content-Type` to get passed to the remote service

Answer (score 6):

Building on Bruce's answer, you will also need to tokenize "-X PUT". Tested out on groovy 2.3.6. `["curl", "-H", "Content-Type: application/json", "-H", "Accept: application/json", "-X", "PUT", "-d", data, uri].execute()`

Answer (score 1):

This works in my terminal

```
groovy -e "println 'curl -i -H \'Content-Type:application/json\' -XPUT -d \'{\"test\":4}\' http://google.fr/'.execute().text"
```

If it does not work for you, then this is likely not a groovy problem.

Comment: Well yes this does not work for me :( It throws the same error -- 415 Content Type Cannot be Consumed

Comment: which groovy version? `groovy -v`. Mine is `Groovy Version: 1.8.4 JVM: 1.6.0_26`

Comment: Groovy Version: 1.6.4 JVM: 1.6.0_26

Comment: maybe you should try this with a newer version of groovy

Comment: Sorry but even after updating to latest groovy version, I keep on seeing the same output.

Comment: This is strange. I mean there is no reason google answer this! Well then i need a bigger stacktrace. What error on your server side ?

Answer (score 1):

Thanks xynthy for the list variation hint, I was still seeing the dreaded 
"Content type 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' not supported"
with your example, but breaking up the -H and the content type strings worked.

This is confirmed working in groovy 1.8:

```
["curl",  "-H", "Content-Type: application/json", "-H", "Accept: application/json", "-X PUT", "-d", data, uri].execute().text
```

Comment: You will also need to tokenize "-X PUT". Tested out on groovy 2.3.6.    ```["curl",  "-H", "Content-Type: application/json", "-H", "Accept: application/json", "-X",  "PUT", "-d", data, uri].execute()```

Comment: ergh, why does it prepend "Result:"? to the response JSON!

Answer (score 0):

First I installed the groovy post build plugin

https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Groovy+Postbuild+Plugin

Then I have included groovy post build plugin in my post build configuration of my jenkins job

and used the command

```
"curl --request POST http://172.16.100.101:1337/jenkins/build".execute().text
```

Here my endpoint is http:172.16.100.101:1337/jenkins/build